# What is the mechanism by which diarrhea is triggered?

Tags: digestion, physiology, triggers, diarrhea

I know that many things, from stress to pathogens, can cause diarrhea.  But I was curious what in the digestive tract detects that something is wrong (eg are there chemoreceptors which find problems, immune cells which detect pathogens, etc.), and then how is that signal carried to cause the changes needed to produce diarrhea (eg hormonally, through the enteric nervous system, etc.)?  Is there a single answer, or are there many processes?